# Covert table dataframe to json api request in python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I scrape a table on a site using pandas and get a dataframe. I only need one column of data from the dataframe that has long titles. I need to insert these titles into a json api request that looks like this:

```
payload = "{\n    \"campaign_id\": 1,\n    \"identifiers\": [\n        {\n            \"identifier\": \"scraped titles\",\n            \"type\": \"keyword\"\n        }\n    ]\n}"
```

as you can see though each, title is a nested dictionary pair. (i think that's what you'd call it). And therefore I need each title to be iterated as above: `{"identifier":"Scraped Title", "type":"keyword"}` for the whole table.

so what I have is data table: 
Identifier 
1
2
3
4
n

and what I need is

{'identifier': '1', 'type': 'keyword'}, {'identifier': '2', 'type': 'keyword'}, {'identifier': '3', 'type': 'keyword'}, {'identifier': '4', 'type': 'keyword'}, {'identifier': 'n', 'type': 'keyword'}

Thanks!

Comment: Can u post the code that u have tried.

Comment: I haven't really tried any code yet =( sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5...]

# list comprehension..
print([{'identifier': item, 'type': 'keyword'} for item in items])
```

Output

```
[{'identifier': 1, 'type': 'keyword'}, {'identifier': 2, 'type': 'keyword'}..]
```